# Deleting committed username and password from bitbucket repository

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have mistakenly sent API username and password in bitbucket code, how do i delete that line ? Please help, it's in public repo.

Comment: If possible, you should change your password (and username, if possible). Then you don't really need to worry about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mercurial is immutable so undoing this kind of action is quite tricky. One way to do it would be to clone your repo up to the revision before you made this commit, throw the old repo away and replace it with your clone and hope that nobody has pulled from the original repo in the meantime.

This thread discusses this and other approaches in more detail: [How do I permanently remove (obliterate) files from history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702381/how-do-i-permanently-remove-obliterate-files-from-history)